# select2 multiple dropdown doesn't get repopulated with original values after clearing selected value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

while selecting a value through multi select in select2 value gets deleted from list and is shown in selected value . but if i clear value using

```
$("#mySel2").select2('data', null);
```

value gets cleared from selected option but it is not added back to dropdown list/original list of value.Though it works fine in case of single value selection.
Any pointer or direction will be of great help.

```
<select id="mySel2" multiple="multiple">
   <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My advise is to use native angular directive: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select